# CSS image as large as possible within square with caption no gap

Tags: css

I'm 99% sure about this but thought i'd ask to see if anyone knew of any clever solutions.

Basically I wish to place an image in a 1/1 aspect containing element, and then for that image to be as as as it possibly can be, eg, landscape images always touch the left and right sides and portrait ones touch the top and bottom.

I then want a line of caption text underneath the image.

My question is, is there any way to get that size of image but without (for landscape images) the large gap between the photo and the caption?

My example image below shows the problem (please note the image is not full left to right edge here like I want).

Anyone know of any clever options to achieve this?

[image]

```
<figure class="photo-1 landscape">
                    <div class="image-wrapper gallery">
                        <a href="https://farm66.staticflickr.com/65535/48808899778_bb1d4d1272_b.jpg" data-pswp-width="4032" data-pswp-height="3024" target="_blank">
                            <img src="https://farm66.staticflickr.com/65535/48808899778_bb1d4d1272_m.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <figcaption><a href="/parks/hersheypark-hershey">Hersheypark</a></figcaption>
                </figure>

figure {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.5rem;

    .image-wrapper {
        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    }

    a {
        display: block;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    &.landscape {
        a {
            min-width: 100%;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    &.portrait {
        a {
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        img {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }

    figcaption {
        text-align: center;
        color: hsl(var(--color-secondary));
        font-size: var(--fs--1);
    }
}
```

Comment: no stack snippet?

Comment: @Anilkumar That margin won't solve the issue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/PoBgZEe

Comment: This problem occur because you put `aspect-ratio: 1/1;`; Your given image's aspect ratio is not `1/1`

Comment: @sean  Yeh object-fit sort of works but doesn't allow me to close that gap whilst keeping the images as large as possible within a square container.

Comment: @Anilkumar I know that. That's why i posted to see if anyone had a clever solution to this tricky layout issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got so far.

```css
body {
  background-color: #F8F9F9;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image.hor {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image.ver {
  flex-direction: column;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.image img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image hor">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      Landscape image (small)
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image hor">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x500/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      Landscape image (large)
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="image ver">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x100/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      Portrait image (small)
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image ver">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x1000/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      Portrait image (large)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou. In your demo, it's the area in between the image and the caption i want to eliminate

Comment: Check the updated version.

Comment: Thanks.  That's pretty close.  I just need to ensure that the width of this component is flexible and that the width of the horizontal ones equal the height of the portrait ones.

Comment: Flexible how? Relative to what?

Comment: i will be using this in containers of different widths so it has to work at all sizes.  I cannot specify exact dimensions.

Comment: I think I now have a workable solution.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Ok, so:
1. Dynamic width
2. For landscape images - height is dynamic?
3. For portrait images - height is equal to width?

Comment: landscape the images are left to right full width.  portrait images, the height should equal the width of the container.  From your code above I have found a workable solution.  Please don't worry anymore.  I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Oh, not worried at all, this is just an interesting challenge.

Comment: Anyway, I think I got it fully working. With images smaller and larger than the container.